# dnd-unescape-uri is undefined

Tags: warning, emacs27

After updating packages from MELPA, I'm getting the message:

`Warning (emacs): dnd-unescape-uri is undefined. Some things may not work.`

It is a separate buffer. Not in the messages buffer.
I can just close the buffer and Emacs seems to be working alright.

I'm using Emacs 27.1 with the Spacemacs layer.

Two questions: Is this dangerous? And what can I do about this?

Comment: Same problem for me today. Are you using `org-ref`? This could be related to this issue: https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues/812

Comment: What is the question? Please say clearly what you are asking (e.g. problem to be solved).

Comment: This has been fixed by an `org-ref` update today.

Comment: Thanks @Philopolis. This would be my accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem for me after updating org-ref. It is linked to the fix related to the issue mentioned by @Philopolis: https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/commit/a7d24f48fe6416162cb1f32d9b87934b9e6c563d

If you want to avoid this warning message at startup, a (temporary) solution is to set

```
(setq warning-minimum-level :emergency)
```